# What is the best build-in function to pick or select given element in a huge list

Tags: compile, number-theory, cryptography

im looking for a best and efficient function works like a search engine 
it takes for example m=5+6I ,then it goes searching in the list V={1,1+I,2+3I,...}
until catch it .
My Dr said to use "Select[]", but im not sure if its efficient if the size of V is more than 200 element.

Comment: That depends on the concrete setup. Sorry, I did not understand your example. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: If i have m=1+5*I as Gaussian integer i want to use a function to search for it in the complete residue system of guassian integers Zn[i]={a+ib/a,b are in Z_{n}}

Comment: And when you found it? What's next? If you `Pick` or `Select` it, the selected values is still equal to `m`. Maybe you want to know the _position_ of `m` within a given list of Gaussian integers?

Comment: yes the function will return to me the position of it

Comment: How is your list represented? If it's just a normal list then searching in it takes the time at least the time required to read it.

Comment: Normal list  with more than 200 element in side it

Comment: @user202729 That's not true. It can be done in logarithmic time with `Nearest`.

Comment: Try `Position[V, 1 + I]`

Comment: @user202729 There was previously comment about sorted lists. It seems to have gone now.

Answer (score 1):

Here a basis example how to use `Nearest` to perform the search in $\log(n)$ time where $n$ is the length of the list $V$.

```
k = 1000;
V = Flatten[Outer[Plus, Range[k], I Range[k]], 1];
NV = N[V];
nf = Nearest[NV -> Automatic]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
mlist = RandomInteger[{1, k}, {1000, 2}].{1, I};
positions = nf[N[mlist], {1, 0.}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Extract[V, positions] == mlist
```

> 0.060709
>
> 0.001179
>
> True

Notice that applying the search to each of the  elements 100000 in `mlist` is dominant; the total runtime of the call to `nf` is the same for `k = 100`, `k = 1000`, and `k = 10000` (i.e., $n = 10000$, $n = 1000000$, and $n = 100000000$).

The trick is that `Nearest` uses a [$k$d-tree data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) to organize the data points for fast lookup.

For comparison, here is a straight-forward implementation with `Position`; each lookup has complexity $O(n)$:

```
positions2 = Position[V, #] & /@ mlist; // AbsoluteTiming // First
positions == Join @@ positions2
```

> 32.9766
>
> True

That takes about 28000 times longer.

Comment: This assumes OP has multiple nearest/contains query. If they have only one then the obvious algorithm is still (asymptotically) optimal.